# Render and Process loop synchronisation with threads

Tags: c++, rendering, thread-synchronization

I am developing an interactive visualizer for a project using Pangolin and OpenGL. The idea is as follows.

There are two threads and I am using double buffering for my solution:

| 1. Render Thread | 2. Process Thread |
| --- | --- |
| - acquire lock and swap `dataNew` with `dataDisplay`, release lock - render `dataDisplay` on the window | - read data - process data - acquire lock, copy data to `dataNew` buffer, release lock |

Sample code:

```
// Render loop
while (!pangolin::ShouldQuit()) {
  if (mDataReadDone) break;

  // ....some code.....

  /*Critical section*/
  // Can acquire lock only after mDataNew 
  // is updated with new data in the process thread
  {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mRenderMutex);
      std::swap(mDataDisplay, mDataNew);
  } /*Critical section*/

  // .....Render mDataDisplay data.........
}

// data process loop
while (!mWindowClosed) {
  // .....Read data....

  // .....Process data....

  // ....Copy data.....
  /*Critical section*/
  {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mRenderMutex);
      copyDataFromPipeline(mDataNew);
  }

}
```

**Question**: In the render loop, for the `std::swap()` to happen, it has to wait till new data is filled in `mDataNew` buffer by the process thread and hence the render loop is blocked for some time. Can the render loop be blocked for some time by design in general? Is there a way for the render loop to not be blocked ?

**Caveat** - In my case, I have a pause option and also a time travel option to go back in frames to debug a particular frame if something is wrong there, so I cannot miss any frames for rendering

Comment: The process thread can do the same trick as the render thread: build the data in some third buffer, then swap it with `mDataNew` under the mutex. This way, on both threads, the mutex is held for only a brief moment, enough to switch pointers around. In fact, you can use atomic exchange instead and get rid of the lock altogether.

Comment: Even with the third buffer I cannot get rid of lock right? Assume no atomic exchange for now

Comment: Well, you need *some* synchronization when sharing data between two threads. Either locks or atomics.

Comment: Sure, when we switch to C++ 20, I can use atomic ops on shared pointers, right now its mutex :)

Comment: You can use atomics on raw pointers since C++11.